# Memory leak in reading files from Google Cloud Storage at Google App Engine (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memory-leaks, google-cloud-storage, webapp2

Below is part of the python code running at Google App Engine.
It fetches a file from Google Cloud Storage by using cloudstorage client.

The problem is that each time the code reads a big file(about 10M), the memory used in the instance will increase linearly. Soon, the process is terminated due to "Exceeded soft private memory limit of 128 MB with 134 MB after servicing 40 requests total".

```
class ReadGSFile(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        import cloudstorage as gcs

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "file type"
        read_path = "path/to/file"

        with gcs.open(read_path, 'r') as fp:
            buf = fp.read(1000000)
            while buf:
                self.response.out.write(buf)
                buf = fp.read(1000000)
            fp.close()
```

If I comment out the following line, then memory usage in instance does change. So it should be the problem of webapp2.

```
  self.response.out.write(buf)
```

It is supposed that webapp2 will release memory space after finishing the response. But in my code, it does not.

Comment: you can only write once to the response object.

Comment: The out stream buffers all output in memory, then sends the final output when the handler exits. webapp does not support streaming data to the client. You need the channel API for streaming.

Comment: I tried to write to response object only one time:   
"buf = fp.read(20000000); self.response.out.write(buf); fp.close(); ". But it does not solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggested by above user voscausa's comment, I changed the scheme for file downloading, that is, to serve file downloading by using Blobstore. Now the problem of memory leak is solved.

Reference:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage

```
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers

class GCSServingHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self):
    read_path = "/path/to/gcs file/"  # The leading chars should not be "/gs/"
    blob_key  = blobstore.create_gs_key("/gs/" + read_path)

    f_name = "file name"
    f_type = "file type" # Such as 'text/plain'

    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = f_type
    self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"%s\";"%f_name
    self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] += " filename*=utf-8''" + urllib2.quote(f_name.encode("utf8"))

    self.send_blob(blob_key)
```

Comment: THANK YOU -- this saved me -- was having the same problem -- memory leaks on GCS access!

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing in-context cache.

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

context = ndb.get_context()
context.clear_cache()
```

[See documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache#incontext)

> With executing long-running queries in background tasks, it's possible
>   for the in-context cache to consume large amounts of memory. This is
>   because the cache keeps a copy of every entity that is retrieved or
>   stored in the current context. To avoid memory exceptions in
>   long-running tasks, you can disable the cache or set a policy that
>   excludes whichever entities are consuming the most memory.

You can also try clearing webapp2 response object buffers. Insert this line of code before *while loop*

```
self.response.clear()
```

> The response buffers all output in memory, then sends the final output
>   when the handler exits. webapp2 does not support streaming data to the
>   client. The clear() method erases the contents of the output buffer,
>   leaving it empty.

[Check this link](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/response.html#)

Comment: I add the cache-clearing code but it does not work. By the way, in my app, I use db, not ndb, to create model. Thus, it seems that the problem itself has no relation with ndb caching.

Comment: I have tested the way to clear buffer of response but failed to solve the problem.That is, call "self.response.clear()" before writing data to buffer in the while loop. But the memory buffer for response is not released. It seems that the caching mechanism in response is different from data buffering.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced similar problem. In my code I sequentially download quite a few  1-10MB files, do some processing on all of them, and then publish results to the cloud.

I have witnessed severe memory leaks being unable to process more then 50-100 downloads in a row.

Being reluctant to rewrite the download code to Blobstore I have tried a last resort experiment, manually calling garbage collection after each download:

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

I am now running the code for several minutes without any  "Exceeded soft private memory limit " and memory footprint of the instance seems to be increasing in a much slower rate.

Obviously, it may be just a good luck, footprint is still gradually increasing, but with some drops, and the instance has already served 2000 requests.